How to pass parameters to sparkR::sql() using dbutils widgets
I am working in databricks using widgets to parameterize my notebook. I want to then pass the widget values as parameters in my sql query using sparkR::sql() to filter my table on. Here is my code:
#creates text widget
dbutils.widgets.text(name = "val1", defaultValue = "Enter val1:")

#defines R variable using value supplied in text widget
x1 <- dbutils.widgets.get("val1")

sparkR.session()
df <- SparkR::sql("
select *
from my_table
where my_val = {x1}
")

I am utilizing the brackets here to show what I have tried. My understanding is that this notation works with pyspark, but does not work with SparkR.
As seen above, I attempted to utilize brackets to parameterize my query; however, this results in the following error: Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) :
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
missing STRING at '}' Is there an alternative notation that I should be using? I tried escaping with single quotes but that did not work either.

Just use base::paste0 to concat the string contents and R constant character variables. You may also use glue::glue to reduce typing, like what you tried already, https://glue.tidyverse.org/
